# criptografar arquivos

Tags: php, aplicação-web, imagem, criptografia

Gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de criptografar **videos**, **imagens**, **etc**... sem ser apenas texto, com PHP, SQL, alguma linguagem **WEB**, estou querendo fazer algo que mantenha a segurança de arquivos, que se a pessoa for fazer download irá receber um arquivo totalmente inútil para ela

Comment: Pelo que sei com `file_get_contents` você consegue pegar todo o dado de qualquer arquivo, sendo textos, imagens ou até mesmo vídeos, em forma de string. Depois disso você pode utilizar qualquer algoritmo de criptografia para estes dados. Nunca testei com vídeos, mas com imagem funciona normalmente. Agora só tem a questão de peso. Pois um arquivo de vídeo transformado em string e depois criptografado vai ficar grande pra caramba, o que pode até travar seu sistema por muito tempo. Não seria mais fácil vc compactar os arquivos em ZIP com senha?? Qual seria sua real utilização??

Comment: um tipo de "netflix" onde a pessoa iria poder baixar para ver, mas somente no site, seria usado cache do navegador, e se a pessoa for tentar baixar o video iria vir criptografado

Comment: Ahh entendi, mas acho que não teria como você fazer isso com php não. Como eu disse sobrecarregaria o servidor pelo tamanho do arquivo. Vou colocar na resposta sobre como a Netflix transmite seus vídeos.

Comment: ok, se puder agradeço

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a sua resposta por querer transmitir vídeo criptografado ao mesmo modo da NetFlix, creio que sua necessidade não seja possível fazer por criptografia em PHP.

Netflix, iTunes, Amazon Prime Videos, Globo Play, etc são serviços de referência na utilização de DRM (Digital Rights Management) para proteção de seus conteúdos. Afinal, os grandes estúdios de Hollywood não querem que seus filmes possam ser baixados e distribuídos tão facilmente através desses novos serviços pagos de vídeo “on demand”.

A DRM foi uma solução encontrada para minimizar e proteger o download e distribuição ilegal de mídias, como áudio e vídeo.

Basicamente, vídeos que trabalham com DRM são criptografados e precisam de uma licença para poderem ser executados. A grande diferença nesse caso, é que, diferentemente do HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) com criptografia, a licença é enviada diretamente para um CDM (Content Decription Media). O CDM normalmente vem instalado por padrão nos browsers para que eles sejam capazes de descriptografar os arquivos protegidos pela DRM.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hoje temos 3 principais CDMs no mercado:

1. **Widevine**, da Google que normalmente vem instalada por padrão no Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc.
2. **Play Ready**, da Microsoft e é a solução utilizada pelo Microsoft Edge por exemplo.
3. **Fair Play**, da Apple, utilizada especificamente pelo Safari.

A parte mais interessante do processo é como a DRM gera essa licença, permitindo que um determinado usuário possa assistir a um conteúdo. De maneira simplificada temos:

Cada vídeo no formato MPEG-DASH possui um “arquivo de manifesto” possuindo a key que foi utilizada para criptografar seus fragmentos. Normalmente esse arquivo possui a extensão “mpd”.

Quando uma solicitação de reprodução do vídeo é realizada, o browser envia para o servidor os dados do vídeo mais as informações específicas do usuário que solicita a licença. O servidor de DRM faz uma requisição de volta para o servidor de aplicação “perguntando” se o usuário tem a permissão para ver especificamente aquele vídeo. O servidor de aplicação responde SIM ou NÃO. Caso sim, o servidor de DRM libera (issue) a licença que é passada para o CDM do browser e o vídeo é finalmente reproduzido.

Isso significa que se você baixar todos os fragmentos dos arquivos do MPEG-DASH, você não será capaz de descriptografar e nem mesmo conseguir o “certificado” como acontece no HLS. A única forma de conseguir a licença é através da autenticação da DRM.

A grande desvantagem da DRM, é que ela é uma solução cara, principalmente pelo fato de precisamos de pelo menos 3 empresas para fornecer esse serviço: Google, Microsoft e Apple.

Fonte com mais informações: https://blog.schoolofnet.com/2017/02/tecnologias-de-video-entenda-como-funcionam-e-qual-delas-implementamos-com-nosso-novo-player/

---

Neste link você também terá mais informações sobre como proteger e criptografar esses vídeos:

http://pt.artistscope.com/video_pt.asp

Espero ter ajudado.